# Excel NumberFormat error, Python with win32com.client

Tags: python, excel, formatting, win32com

I have a problem with a Python function that uses win32com.client to format an excel worksheet that has been previously created in the function. The code snippet is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
import pywintypes as pywt

# open MS Excel
excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')

# open required workbook
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
worksheet_name = 'This Sheet'
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'Result1': result1, 'Result2': result2})

# close workbook to do the writing
workbook.Close(True)

# write data to Excel
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, mode='a') as writer:
    df_data.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=worksheet_name, startrow=3)

end_hdr_row = 3
electricity_price = 0.12  # actually, this variable comes from another function, type float
currency = 'USD'  # actually, this variable comes from another function, type string

# do the formatting
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(worksheet_name)

worksheet.Range("B" + str(end_hdr_row)).Value = electricity_price

# format number
worksheet.Range("A3:B10").NumberFormat = currency + " #,##0.00"  # this works, "USD 1,234.00" displayed
worksheet.Range("B" + str(end_hdr_row)).NumberFormat = "Power ("+currency+"/kWh)" + " #,##0.00"  # results in error

workbook.Save()
workbook.Close(True)
```

The first NumberFormat line works, the second one results in the error

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

The cell is not protected, nor is the worksheet. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? I'm pretty new to Python so not much experience on my side. I appreciate any help! Thank you!!!

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like the `/` in the format. You can try to enclose the text part of the format in quotes: `'"Power ('+currency+'/kWh)"' + ' #,##0.00'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It wasn't the ```/``` (it also did not work with other string combinations), but the single quotes did the trick!